# mutiple occurance of single country in google map

Tags: google-maps, jquery-plugins

I use [geocomplete](http://ubilabs.github.com/geocomplete/) plugin for the google map to load the map. When i load the map of "United States" it occur more than once in the map. I think it probably related to size of the map canvas. How could i solve it? I have also this same problem in gmap3, and direct use of google map API.

[image]

Comment: Try to restrict the levels of zoom that causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "hide" the repeated areas in two manners:

I prefer resizing the div as the zoom changes. The drawback is that if you keep the map centered (which I think looks better) the map control moves around and zooming is not predictable like in a fixed-size map

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/eyehaz/3/edit#preview

```
  var map;
  var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0), zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
  var widths = ["256px", "512px", "1024px", "100%"];

  function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
      zoom = map.getZoom();
      if (zoom < 4) {
        document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.width = widths[zoom];
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.width = widths[3]; 
      }
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    });
  }
```

Second option, place invisible divs in the right place and enable their visibility when the zoom level is low. The drawback is that to keep the map centered, the map controls are covered completely

```
  #leftcover { position: absolute; height: 100%; background-color: #e5e3df; left: 0px; width: 128px; z-index: 2; display: none }
  #rightcover { position: absolute; height: 100%; background-color: #e5e3df; left: 384px; width: 128px; z-index: 2; display: none }

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
      if(map.getZoom() == 0) {
        document.getElementById("leftcover").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("rightcover").style.display = "inline";
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("leftcover").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("rightcover").style.display = "none";
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is by design. It appears that in API version 3 there is no way of limiting the horizontal repeat of the map.

You are correct that the size of the map is implicated: because the size and zoom level allows more than one instance of the map, more than one is shown. Each copy gets a marker.