# How to put limit on GMaps and avoid repeating the map?

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to use GMaps but I want to avoid this behaviour:

[image]

I not want to limit the zoom. I want to limit the repetition of the world map.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `MapOptions` object, place a `minZoom`. 3 should do it, but it depends on how big you map div is:

```
   var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 3,
          minZoom:3,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
```

Comment: 3. But the width of div map is 100%. Will increase with the size of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Without restricting zoom, I have seen artificial workarounds. It depends how you have your page set up.

If the map takes up the whole width of the webpage, I think changing the div's width on zoom change is best.

If you have content around the map, you can try setting up gray div "curtains" that block part of the original map's div, so it appears that the map viewport shrunk. The big disadvantage is you will have to cover up the map controls if the viewport needs to stay centered.

See sample code here: [**mutiple occurance of single country in google map**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779992/mutiple-occurance-of-single-country-in-google-map/10789395#10789395)